# How can i use Paypal ipn in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, paypal, routes, paypal-ipn

I trying to pay using paypal form and to get Instant payment Notification after completed payment.

To achieve this i am using the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) Of paypal Settings.

**Already Done :**

1) Enable IPN from paypal Settings

2) Update notify_url in paypal control panel settings.

3) I also set to except the crsf validation for IPN post url in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the 
        response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = ['paypal-ipn/ipnstatus'];
}
```

And add routes in `/routes/web.php`

```
Route::post('paypal-ipn/ipnstatus', 'WalletController@ipnstatus')->name('wallet.ipnstatus');
```

And i write the ipnstatus function in WalletController as below :

```
public function ipnstatus(Request $request){

            \Log::Info("=============== START IPN PROCEESING ==================");
}
```

But it not generate any log and also not heat ipn url.

Can any one please help why ipn url not call. `I am using Laravel version 5.2`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would try to exclude the error: try to change the name of the `ipnstatus' function in the controller and see if you get an error

Comment: @GiacomoM , i have change function name ipnstatus to ipnstatus2 and make payments but in log file i am not getting any error.

Comment: so your problem is that you are not calling your function at all. Your problem is in your POST url. you do not call the right route

Comment: @GiacomoM But when i test the posted ipn url in form post url then its working fine. I am able to post data at that function.

Comment: it makes no sense at all: if you change the name of the function in the controller (and NOT in the route) you MUST get a laravel error.